# How are Sea-Prism Stone items made

Tags: one-piece

Zoro couldn't cut them and they are stated to be as hard as diamond. So how are Sea-Prism Stone items made?

Comment: I think it will definitily be explained in the later Arcs, maybe when Dr. Vegapunk will appear in the manga.

Comment: @pap I think I read somewhere that Oda said *a New World scientist* would appear and tell us more about Devil Fruits soon. Maybe at the end of the current arc? He might also tells us more about seaprism as well.

Comment: Note that you can sometimes abrasion cut a very hard material with its own dust. This also says nothing about whether the material may be brittle or chemically active.  Very hard materials are easy to fracture and diamonds can easily heated into CO2.

Comment: If they were just hard as diamond, Zoro could have cut them (Alabasta arc). Note that not even the bird cage or Franky's beam did any harm to the Sea-Pism coated factory. Since they are SEA-Prisom stone, they may be formable in sea water.

Comment: How do you make diamond rings? Is the question.

Answer (score 1):

In the Alabasta Arc, Smoker revealed that Seastone has "Sea Power" and therefore nullifies abilities just like salt water. In other words, vegapunk discovered its usage, this was revealed by Smoker and confirmed by Coby after Water-Seven Arc.

Vegapunk was able to coat ship bottoms with seastone, enabling them to pass through the calm belt without alerting the Sea monsters to their presence. He discovered a way which is yet unrevealed but confirmed by Coby back then to make tools, handcuffs, and weapons, out of seastone.